# truffle console issues without testrpc running

Tags: truffle, testnets, ropsten

I am attempting to deploy a contract to the ropsten network and having issues with truffle console. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f) tutorial. When I try to access the console with this command -

`$ truffle console`

I get this error:

```
➜  voting truffle console
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse
```

I don't have an issue accessing the console while testrpc is running. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for truffle you need 2 instances of cmd: 
- one with testrpc running 
- one with truffle(.cmd) console

you could use the browser for the ropsten testnet 
http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity

(sorry i have low reputation for comments)

Answer (score 1):

Check your truffle.js file for various networks available. You can add some code yourself if it's not available.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*'
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: provider,
      network_id: 3 // official id of the ropsten network
    }
  }
}
```

You can add something like this and then

```
truffle console --network ropsten
```

Hope that helps.